# What happens to oppty records when merging accounts?

Tags: opportunity, account, merge

when merging accounts in SFDC and both have opps (open and closed) and I want to keep all the data and history for both records, would that be possible? Or will the master account that’s identified be the only data we can keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you start with this:

```
Account Winner
  Oppo 100 Closed
  Oppo 101 Open

Account Loser
  Oppo 200 Open
  Oppo 201 Closed
```

after merge of loser into winner you will have:

```
Account Winner
  Oppo 100 Closed
  Oppo 101 Open
  Oppo 200 Open
  Oppo 201 Closed
```

merge basically reparents all children of the losing Account into the winning account